# awk start edits from line 2?

Tags: csv, awk

i have a testfile.csv of which i want to replace all values in the third column with a new value without touching the header:

```
testfile.csv
col1,col2,col3
a,a,a
b,b,b
```

i tried this code below where i specified NR>1:

```
cat test_file.csv| awk -F"," 'NR>1{OFS=",";{$3="10/1/2015"} print}' >xx
```

my output gives me the below but it also edited the header of col3 which is not what i want:

```
xx
col1,col2,10/1/2015
a,a,10/1/2015
b,b,10/1/2015
```

i want this:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,a,10/1/2015
b,b,10/1/2015
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script should skip the first line. So you should not even see col1,col2,col3. Please make sure that the first line of testfile.csv start with col1,col2,col3.

If you want to see also the first line you need to:

```
cat testfile.csv| awk -F"," '{ if (NR>1) {OFS=",";{$3="10/1/2015"} print} else print}'
```

Comment: Written in idiomatic, robust, efficient awk that'd be: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR>1{$3="10/1/2015"} 1' testfile.csv`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get the same output as you

```
a,a,10/1/2015
b,b,10/1/2015
```

which is what I would have expected.

So the `NR>1` worked for me.

Try

```
echo "col1,col2,col3
a,a,a 
b,b,b" \
| awk -F"," -vOFS=","  'NR==1{print};NR>1{$3="10/1/2015"; print}'
```

**output**

```
col1,col2,col3
a a 10/1/2015
b b 10/1/2015
```

Also if you data has been created in MSWindows environment, and your are now processing in Linux, be sure to remove `\r` chars, with `dos2unix myDataFile.txt`

IHTH

Comment: `awk -F"," -vOFS="," 'NR>1{$3="10/1/2015"} {print}'` is DRYer

Comment: @glennjackman : Thanks for your reminder. Given the OPs level of awk understanding, I deliberately include 2 blocks of code to make the invisible visible ;-) Good luck to all.